# a better way/approach for responsive mobile web/webapp design?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found m.taobao.com automatic change body font-size, base on device width using javascript

```
   (function (doc, win) {
    var docEl = doc.documentElement,
      resizeEvt = 'orientationchange' in window ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize',
      recalc = function () {
        var clientWidth = docEl.clientWidth;
        if (!clientWidth) return;
        var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
        docEl.style.fontSize = (dpr / 2 ) * 100 * (clientWidth  / 360) + 'px';
      };
    if (!doc.addEventListener) return;
    win.addEventListener(resizeEvt, recalc, false);
    doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', recalc, false);
  })(document, window);
```

and all components width/height, layout using rem!
once i open this site with iphone4s the base font-size is:

```
<html data-dpr="2" style="font-size: 64px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
.icon {
  width: 1.203rem;
  height: 1.203rem;
}
```

div.icon get smaller while if i open with iphone6 same .icon css but, icon get bigger

```
<html data-dpr="2" style="font-size: 75px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
```

another way is using media query to do this, but need to write lots of css!
which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Im looking at your post and although this is asked a lot - CSS will always in my opinion be the best method to use for responsive design.

Additionally, the CSS solution is supported down to IE9+ and the fallback option you can use for browsers that dont support media queries are there. e.g https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

You get to choose the media query values according to your content's best break points instead of device dimensions, that way you make sure your content will always look right no matter how many new devices are made.

Another option is using something like twitter bootstrap where it will do most of the work for you by just using classes and then it will respond based on the correct screen size too. http://getbootstrap.com/

Hope this helps but it will in the end be your preference and the code wont be a lot. name your classes correctly and just reuse them accordingly for the queries and you will have a fully functional responsive site.

**Media Query examples:**

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

The link above will give you an idea of what screen sizes can be used to display the content correctly based on the devices

Have fun!